# Running spring boot native application, cannot load resource file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to compile a Spring Boot application to a native application and run this using docker. I'm using spring-graalvm-native version 0.8.5 and Spring Boot version 2.4.1. I'm trying to build the docker container using spring-boot-maven-plugin using the command:

```
mvn spring-boot:build-image
```

In the code, I want to read a file from resources and I'm trying to load it like this:

```
@Value("classpath:my.json")
Resource resourceFile;
```

The compilation step works fine, but the problem is that when I run the docker image my.json file isn't loaded, it cannot be found.

I run *native-image-agent* and it generated the META-INF folder where the resources-config.json file has the my.json pattern added.

I also tried to configure spring-boot-maven-plugin and I added:

```
-H:IncludeResources='.*/my.json$'
```

But none of these configurations worked, can you help me figure out what the problem is?

Best regards

Project structure:

[image]

Comment: Share your project dir structure

Comment: I added it, please tell me if it's ok

Comment: So is the symptom that `resourceFile` is `null` at runtime?  The basic Spring side of things looks fine here, from what you show.  I wouldn't think you'd need any of the additional steps you've mentioned to get the `my.json` file to be found.  It's in the standard location for resource files.  `@Value("classpath:my.json")` should just pick it up.  I don't know about Graal except for what it basically is.  I wonder if your app would work if you weren't using Graal and/or weren't running in a Docker container.  Have you tried eliminating either of these complexities to see the app then works?

Comment: Yes, the resourceFile is null. If I'm running the app using java -jar my.jar it works fin.

Comment: I think you have to use `.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my.json")`

Comment: [Related question (duplicate?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76156392/docker-container-build-with-spring-boot-native-cant-access-files-in-src-main-re)

Answer (score 1):

I could make it work using `RuntimeHintsRegistrar`, from [GraalVM Native Image Support doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.advanced.custom-hints).

Create an implementation of `RuntimeHintsRegistrar`:

```java
public class HintsRegistrar implements RuntimeHintsRegistrar {
    @Override
    public void registerHints(RuntimeHints hints, ClassLoader classLoader) {
        hints.resources().registerPattern("my.json");
    }
}
```

and use it in your `DemoApplication.java`:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportRuntimeHints(HintsRegistrar.class)
public class DemoAppplication {
```